# conversation (n) vs. talk (n)

Tags: meaning, word-choice, differences

I do not understand the difference between conversation (n) and talk (n). I am only interested in the difference in the following definitions:

[**conversation**](http://learnersdictionary.com/definition/conversation) (n):

> 1: an informal talk involving two people or a small group of people :
>   the act of talking in an informal way

[**talk**](http://learnersdictionary.com/definition/talk) (n):

> 1: an occurrence in which one person talks about something with another person : a conversation or discussion
>   
>    2: the act of talking about a subject with another person or group :
>   discussion or conversation

Source: *Merriam-Webster’s Advanced Learner’s English Dictionary*

Some examples to put it into concrete:

- They had a talk/conversation while waiting at the dentist's.
- The conversation/talk got unpleasant.

Comment: What sticks out at me from those definitions is that *conversation* is an **informal** talk, and *talk* seems more formal. "We need to talk about Kevin."

Comment: Note that "conversation" is necessarily two-way.  "Talk" can be one-way.

Comment: This may be true for other definitions of *talk*. But this does not fit to the above definitions to be examined here.            "1: an occurrence in which **one person** talks about something with **another person** : **a conversation** or discussion." and              "2: the act of talking about a subject **with another person** or group : **discussion or conversation**"

Comment: "Talk" occurs in many idioms. You can't work out the meaning of an idiom purely by looking up the individual words in a dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

The primary difference is that "conversation" is necessarily two-way -- two or more people interchanging utterances.

"Talk", on the other hand, *may* involve only a single person speaking, with everyone else in the room just listening (or perhaps ignoring the speaker).  Of course, two people may "talk to each other", in which case they're having a conversation.

Comment: Quote: "Of course, two people may "talk to each other", in which case they're having a conversation." - Yes, and only in this case I am interested in the differences. Please have a look at the definitions above, who will be examined here.

Comment: @Wogehu - The dividing lines are not a sharp as you might want to believe.  Certainly when someone in authority says "I'll have a talk with him" the implication is that the "information" will flow mainly in one direction, but tone of voice and general demeanor carry stronger indications.

Comment: "We need to have a talk about something" implies a conversation, although it can in practice mean a lecture. The OP needs to look at various idiomatic phrases such as "have a talk", "give a talk", etc, in which "talk" means different things.

Answer (score 0):

Conversation- it is a style of communication a dresser and reciever which is purposefully and done in a meaningful way.

Talk- it is a style of communication between a dresser and receiver which is informal and done formal.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).